# Grab href and put it on src

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div that brings a bunch of thumbnails with href links to the full image. So instead of opening this image away from the site, I need to bring this image dynamically in a second div.

Here's what I have 'til now:

- The HTML

  ```
  <article id="thumbnails">

      <a href="large-image-1.jpg">
      <img class="image-99" alt="97" src="thumbnail-1.jpg">
      </a>

      <a href="large-image-2.jpg">
      <img class="image-98" alt="96" src="thumbnail-2.jpg">
      </a>

      <a href="large-image-3.jpg">
      <img class="image-97" alt="95" src="thumbnail-3.jpg">
      </a>

  </article>
  ```

  ```
  <div id="large-image">
      <img id="xxl" src="" title="">
  </div>
  ```
- the jQuery

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#thumbnails').on('click','a', function(event) {

      var toLoad = $(event.target).append('<img src="' + 'attr('src').jpg />"');
      $('#large-image').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);

      function loadContent () {
          $('#large-image').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
      }

      function showNewContent () {
          $('#large-image').fadeIn('normal');
      }

      return false;
    });
  ```

I also did a [codepen of it](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/EmHqv) to illustrate it better.

One thing I'm considering as an alternative is to record the clicked image href and replace the src of the other div with the `attr()` thing. But I got lost in how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try to get the link's `href` and change the target-image's `src`.

```
var largeImage = $('#large-image img');

$('#thumbnails a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var imageUrl = $(this).attr('href'); 

  largeImage.attr('src', imageUrl);
});
```

[Example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ANofaCe/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#thumbnails').on('click','a', function(event) {
    var toLoad = $(this).append('<img src="' + this.href + '.jpg" />');

    //Rest of code
});
```

EDIT: The above code will get the `href` attribute of the clicked link and adds it to the src of the image.

Comment: This answer is of little use to anyone without you actually explaining your code instead of just posting a block of it

Comment: @Bojangles - thanks, I thought OP would understand. _an alternative is to record the clicked image href and replace the src of the other div with the attr() thing_. The answer is based on this.

Comment: Thank you @Krishna! The other answer got what I want but this one also works.